# POST method in React Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

What I have to do if I want: after click button `add` by user I want to induce POST method to database MySQL. I have to do connect to database from another file than server.js, but I get error

```
Net.createConnection is not a function
```

This is my Compontent file

```
import React, { PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { CounterActions } from '../redux/actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import mysql from 'mysql'

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xxx',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : 'xxx',
  database : 'xxx'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!!error){
        console.log('error');
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to db');
    }
})

class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    click(){
        this.props.testClick();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hallow Reduxasd <div></div></h1>
                <h2>Counter: {this.props.global.counter}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Click Me!</button>
                <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
                <h3><Link to={'/user/'+this.props.global.counter}>{'Link do user id: '+this.props.global.counter}</Link></h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Net`? Where's your code?